# How does my View Model Test class know to use a test data file rather than the normal data file?

Tags: android, kotlin, testing, viewmodel

Basically, I am fairly new to Android and Kotlin. This is part of the Android Basics with Compose course. The GitHub repo can be found [here](https://github.com/google-developer-training/basic-android-kotlin-compose-training-unscramble/tree/viewmodel).

I am trying to understand how when I've instantiated a view model in the test class it knows to use the test data set rather than the other data set. There is no import for the file or anything. I really can't get my head around it. Is it just the fact that it is in the test package and I've used the `@Test` annotation? Hopefully, someone can explain.
This is what the test file looks like and you can see the other one as well with the same name but it contains more than just 10 words.

[image: Screenshot]

I have tried looking online for an answer and can't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Using different versions of the same file is possible because they are in different *source sets*. You can find more detailed explanation here: [Source sets](https://developer.android.com/build#sourcesets). TLDR below.

Source sets are logical groups of source files and resources. Directories `src/main/` and `src/test/` contain `main/` and `test/` source sets created by Android Studio. The `main/` source set includes code and resources common to all build variants.

When different source sets contain different versions of the same file, Gradle (build management system used by Android Studio) will prioritize the source set specific version of that file while reusing the rest of the files from the other source sets.

Comment: Thanks so much this is the answer I was looking for. Wasn't aware of source sets. :)

Comment: @MrFlavour glad my answer was useful.